# Do evergreen trees have higher densities of stomata to compensate for retaining leaves?

Tags: trees

According to literature (Walls-Thumma), evergreen trees have less stomata on their leaves (than deciduous trees) to limit water evaporation.

Does this mean they have less less stomata in total, or do they have stomata on the adaxial surface that compensates for the smaller amount of the abaxial surface (in comparison to deciduous trees?).
Thanks!